# Update a number being displayed by div tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some code that displays the number of people viewing a specific twitch.tv stream. It loads the number once and displays it. If someone wants an update on the number of viewers, then they have to refresh the page. Is there a way to refresh the number every few seconds, so that people don't have to refresh the page? the code is below (its the div id=viewers that i want to update)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script></head></html>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

    var channelName = "crossgamechat";


    function showViewers(a){
    alert(a.viewers_count);
    }
    $.getJSON("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/summary.json?channel="+ channelName + "&jsonp=?", function(a){document.getElementById("viewers").innerHTML  += a.viewers_count;}); 
    ;  

    </script>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div style="width: 100px;">
     <div id="viewers" style="float: left"></div>
     <div id="blank" style="float: left; width: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
     <div id="divtext" style="float: left;">Viewers</div>
     <br style="clear: left;"/>
    </div>
    </head></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) to run a specific function at a set interval.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/tt5NH/

jQuery:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/summary.json?channel=" + channelName + "&jsonp=?", function(data) {
        document.getElementById("viewers").innerHTML = data.viewers_count;
    });
}, 2000);
```

P.S. Your jQuery library is outdated and you have a few syntax errors.

Comment: thanks a lot! Your code is helping me learn some stuff about html that was confusing me. The updated numbers aren't displaying on my site, but it's probably some simple mistake i'm making.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a setInterval method

```
window.setInterval(function () {

    $.getJSON("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/summary.json?channel="+ channelName + "&jsonp=?", function(a){document.getElementById("viewers").innerHTML  += a.viewers_count;}); 


}, 5000);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ajax call inside a setInterval to do so. Send a get or post request to a page that returns the number to display, then on success of that call update the span/div or whatever is displaying the number

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4TJXV/)